# Access the offset of the current match in the callback function of preg_replace_callback()

Tags: php, regex, offset, preg-replace-callback

How can I keep track of the current match’s offset from the start of the string in the callback of [`preg_replace_callback`](https://www.php.net/preg_replace_callback)?

For example, in this code, I’d like to point to the location of the match that throws the exception:

```php
$substituted = preg_replace_callback('/{([a-z]+)}/', function ($match) use ($vars) {
    $name = $match[1];

    if (isset($vars[$name])) {
        return $vars[$name];
    }

    $offset = /* ? */;
    throw new Exception("undefined variable $name at byte $offset of template");
}, $template);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of PHP 7.4.0, `preg_replace_callback` also accepts the `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` flag, turning every match group into a `[text, offset]` pair:

```php
$substituted = preg_replace_callback('/{([a-z]+)}/', function ($match) use ($vars) {
    $name = $match[1][0];

    if (isset($vars[$name])) {
        return $vars[$name];
    }

    $offset = $match[0][1];
    throw new Exception("undefined variable $name at byte $offset of template");
}, $template, flags: PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
```

Comment: Time to move that green tick, I reckon (rather than promoting a workaround).

Answer (score 7):

As the marked answer is no longer available, here's what worked for me to get current index of replacement:

```
$index = 0;
preg_replace_callback($pattern, function($matches) use (&$index){
    $index++;
}, $content);
```

As you can see we have to maintain the index ourselves with the use of out-of-scope variable.

Comment: The index of the match in the string, not the number of previous matches.

Comment: If by index you mean position, then it makes sense

Comment: This is the correct answer to a different question.

Answer (score 2):

You can match first with [`preg_match_all`](https://php.net/preg_match_all) & `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` option and rebuild your string, instead of using the default `preg_replace` method.